# show robot trajectory in rviz real-time

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, I want to show UAV's trajectory in RVIZ in real time.
I am not sure I can use  LINE_STRPS  in visualization_msgs::Marker or PATH in nav_msgs/Path. The navigation algorithm was done by myself. I just want to show the trajectory, i am not sure which message to show path in rviz.
Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209224/show-robot-trajectory-in-rviz-real-time/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to add to the options mentioned by others: you could perhaps also look at [moveit_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools) by Dave Coleman. From [README.md](https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools/blob/indigo-devel/README.md):

> Animate Trajectories

> Higher level robot and trajectory functions

> - **publishTrajectoryPath**
> - publishTrajectoryPoint
> - publishRobotState
> - publishAnimatedGrasps
> - publishIKSolutions

`publishTrajectoryPath(..)` would seem to fit with what you describe.

Edit: whether this would work obviously depends on what particular type of *robot trajectory* you are working with.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-05-15**:
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `nav_msgs/Odometry` message, but the pose is drawn as a series of arrows, and they can look a little clunky if you are only concerned with position and not orientation. In those cases, I tend to use the `nav_msgs/Path` type.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-05-15**:
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) package to conveniently generate a `nav_msgs/Path` message as described by Tom.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-05-15**:
thanks for your help

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-05-22**:
It worked for me!